# How to embed inline image in email using Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to embed a logo as an image in email.

When i use the `<img src="{{ $message->embed($pathToImage) }}">` function i get an error

> Unable to open file for reading [https://roadshow.test/storage/img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png]

The Email builder look like this:

```
return $this->subject("Event - {$subjectDate}")
                    ->view('emails.index')
                    ->with(['pathToImage' => url('/storage/img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png')]);
```

If i use the `url('....')` function in my View, the picture is loading and I can see it without any problems.

I have also tried to get the image with the Laravel `public_path('/img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png')` helper. But this is not working altought i linked the storage with public folder with the php artisan command.

my filesystem config:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
],

'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
 ],
```

and I don't use a email markdown. The enviroment is set up on homestead. All my files are in `"/home/vagrant/code/roadshow/storage/img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png"` folder uploaded.

I'm running homestead on Windows 10 and this is the path in Windows

[image]

Comment: Have you used the `symlink` command to create a symlink between your `storage` and the `public` folder?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in my question. I used this command `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: I read over that part, my bad!

Comment: You have to pass it the storage path not the url or public path. You can use the storage_path helper for this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-storage-path if you need more help, please provide us the location of the file within the project.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your email builder, the name of the attribute hint for a `path` not a `link`.
Try it with the direct path, since you are embedding the image to your mail body.

```
return $this->subject("Event - {$subjectDate}")
                ->view('emails.index')
                ->with(['pathToImage' => storage_path('app/public/img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png')]);
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm getting the same error when I use the `storage_path('img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png')`.

Comment: @GregOstry starting from your installation folder, where is the file in question located exactly ? for example, i guessed it was at `/var/www/installation/storage/img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png`

Comment: this is the typical laravel installation on homestead: `"/home/vagrant/code/<Project>"` and the this is the full path to the image from the project installation: `"roadshow/storage/img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png"` when i die and dump on `storage_path('...')` i get this path: `"/home/vagrant/code/roadshow/storage/img/Email/Image_1_3a24d02162cb4c38a9c97009d527d53c.png"`

Comment: @GregOstry i've edited my answer, can you try it now ?